# Am I correctly mounting my camera on a MH055M8-Q5 Manfrotto Photo-Video Head?

Tags: tripod-heads

[MH055M8-Q5](http://www.manfrotto.com/product/8374.31708.83523.0.0/MH055M8-Q5/_/055_MAG_PHOTO-MOVIE_HEAD_Q5) just arrived. Once I mount the camera on the quick release plate, I can't seem to rotate the knob to completely tighten it, there is no room because the camera obstructs the knob. Can someone please let me know if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post a photo of how you are doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the features on many Manfrotto heads is that the quick-release plate knobs are spring-loaded... Essentially this will enable you to pull the knobs outward which will allow them to be readjusted without tightening (or loosening) the underlying bolt. This gives the ability to 'ratchet tighten' the bolt by shifting the knob when space gets tight.

Comment: Yeah, let us know. I'm pretty sure this is what's going on for you, so if I know for sure I'll update the answer so its less speculative sounding...